# I am getting a Maximum Call Stack error and not sure why?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

```
const isPrime = (number) => {
  return count = (currNum = 2) => {
    if(currNum === number) {
      return true;
    }
    if(number%currNum === 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return count(currNum+1);
    }
  }
}

const largestPrime = (number) => {
  let currLargest = 0;
  return count = (currNum = 2) => {
    if(currNum > number) {
      return currLargest;
    } else {
      if(isPrime(currNum)()){
        currLargest = currNum;
      }
      console.log(currLargest);
      return count(currNum+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Learning functional programming and practicing recursion, currying, and closure.
`isPrime(5)()` returns true, and `isPrime(6)()` returns false
however, when i run largestPrime I run into a call stack error.

2
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at count (REPL13:2:18)
at count (REPL13:9:14)
at count (REPL13:9:14)
at count (REPL13:9:14)
at count (REPL13:9:14)
at count (REPL13:9:14)
at count (REPL13:9:14)
at count (REPL13:9:14)
at count (REPL13:9:14)
at count (REPL13:9:14)

the currLargest displays as supposed to, meaning the second it hits **return count(currNum+1);** it gets into the error. Is there anything wrong with my code that is creating an infinite loop? I've been looking over it for a bit now, and I cannot see anything wrong with it. Its extra confusing because isPrime is similarly structured to largestPrime, and isPrime is working as expected.

largestPrime is supposed to simply return the largest prime less than or equal to a number. I know I could've looped backwards and stopped at the first prime, but I couldn't even get the forward to work yet!

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/puficebano/edit?js,console). How exactly do you call `largestPrime()` to get a stack overflow?

Comment: it returns a function so you need to add () to it. so largestPrime(10)()

Comment: [Always `"use strict"` mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), it would have caught this bug! You've got an undeclared global `count` that is [implicitly created by assignment](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but test the following in a playground and it is working:

```
const isPrime = (number) => {
  return count = (currNum = 2) => {
    if(currNum === number) {
      return true;
    }
    if(number%currNum === 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return count(currNum+1);
    }
  }
}

const largestPrime = (number) => {
  let currLargest = 0;
  return count2 = (currNum = 2) => {
    if(currNum > number) {
      return currLargest;
    } else {
      if(isPrime(currNum)()){
        currLargest = currNum;
      }
      return count2(currNum+1);
    }
  }
}

console.log(largestPrime(555)())
```

Basically, rename the internal function with another name different from the first one.

I've been 8+ developing JS and will find a search now for what has happened.

Can you check? Waiting for someone to give a proper explanation.

*UPDATE*

Here is the explanation:

> If you assign a value to a variable that you have not declared with
> var , JavaScript implicitly declares that variable for you. Note,
> however, that implicitly declared variables are always created as
> global variables, even if they are used within the body of a function.

Taken from [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596101996/ch04.html)

Comment: ok, still the same when using a laaaarge number....

Comment: but in Javascript, i was told that var should not be used because it has global scope, and to use const and let because scope applies. wondering why then the 2 internal functions cannot have the same name. 
edit: nevermind i got it! i never declared the variable since it is return, so im guessing javascript implicitly declared it a var with global scope?

Comment: @HenryZhang because they aren't "internal". They are implicit globals. And more specifically both manipulate the same global identifier `count`. "*i was told that var should not be used because it has global scope,*" no, that's not correct at all. A `var` in a function will be scoped to that function. It's inadvisable to use `var` because doesn't get scoped to a block. "*and to use const and let because scope applies*" and you didn't use either.

Comment: no, everything applies to the scope. If you declare a variable above all functions and closures it will be visible to all, no matter if `var, let, or const`. In your case, JS declares the first `count` variable as global, because you do not specify the modifier

Comment: As for the answer - instead of perpetuating the extremely bad practice of using implicit globals - just use named functions. That's *why* named functions exist, so they can have a self-reference to themselves.

Comment: so to confirm, rather than directly returning the function, i should declare it as a const or let and then return the name of the function directly? makes sense, i will try to do that more

Comment: @HenryZhang In this case it would make a lot more sense to just make it a named function expression. Not that `const` or `let` won't work but if you want a self-invoking function, it's just the better choice. Shorter and it's self-contained, meaning it can be refactored easier, if needed.

Comment: "*rename the internal function with another name different from the first one*" - that's not sufficient. The `isPrime` function still is executed multiple times and still creates multiple different functions that are all assigned to `count`.

Comment: oh i see so rather than using arrow function () => initialize like function() {}. whats the difference? i thought it was pretty much the same except this properties? and arrows are not hoisted?